# If $m,n\in \Bbb Z$ show that there exists $p\in \Bbb Z$ such that $\gcd(m,p)=1;\gcd(n,p)=1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

True/False:

> If $m,n\in \Bbb Z\setminus \{1,0\}$ such that $\gcd(m,n)\neq1$,show that there exists $p(\neq 1,0)\in \Bbb Z$ such that $\gcd(m,p)=1;\gcd(n,p)=1$.

I think it is true.

If $\gcd(m,n)\neq1\implies \gcd(m,n)=p$

If $p=m$ then $m\mid n$ ,we choose $k$ such that $\gcd(k,m)=1$ which implies $\gcd(k,n)=1$ and so we are done.

Similarly if $p=n$ then the result follows.

Now if $p\neq m,n$ then I am getting stuck. Because if I take $(4,6)$ then $\gcd(4,6)=2$ but if I choose $p=3$ where $\gcd(2,3)=1 $but $\gcd(3,6)\neq 1$.

Please help.

Comment: Is $p$ supposed to be prime? Wh can't youuse $p=1$?

Comment: Yes $p\neq 1$@ThomasAndrews;i missed writing that

Comment: You don't need the condition $\gcd(m,n)\neq 1$. It's true for all pairs,$m,n$, with $m\neq 0$ and $n\neq 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $p=|mn|+1.$ Then if $d\mid m$ and $d\mid p$ it would follow that $d\mid 1,$ so this gives $\gcd(m,p)=1.$ Similar argument for $\gcd(n,p)=1.$

Note that this argument does not rely on the assumption $\gcd(m,n) \neq 1$ of the problem as posed.

Comment: This is constructive without appealing to infinitude of primes, +1.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** If $n$ and $m$ are both nonzero, each has finitely many divisors, and there are infinitely many primes.

Comment: This is not a hint, almost an answer, but +1 for this.